# Entity Framework 6 Include missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a project broken into separate classes for an MVC project using Entity Framework 6. One class has a Generic Interface and then it is inherited

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
}
```

Inherited as below

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly DbContext _context = null;
    private readonly DbSet<T> _entities;

    public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _entities = _context.Set<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _entities;
    }
}
```

This works fine and i then use this in a customer class as below

```
public class CustomerRepository : Repository<Customer>, ICustomerRepository
{
    public CustomerRepository(DataContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public List<Customer> GetPremiumCustomers()
    {
        return GetAll().Where(p => p.Premium).ToList();
    }
}
```

So far so good and everything returns as expected.

I need to Include a couple of additional tables that are linked to the customers.

When i go to the `Repository` class and against `_entities` i press the **.** key i see `Include` in the menu.

I then go into the `CustomerRepository` and do the same with `GetAll().` and along other methods along that line but `Include` isnt shown?

I tried adding using `System.Data.Entity` to the top of the `Customer` class but that didnt bring the option either but it is available in the top most class? What am i missing here?

I was trying to achieve something along the lines of

```
GetAll().Include("Address").Where(p => p.Premium).ToList()
```

Comment: The type `DbContext` is an implementation of a UoW pattern and the type `DbSet<T>` is an implementation of a Repository pattern. Why re-wrap these types in your own implementation of the same pattern? You are adding nothing of value, just more code and a poor abstraction which results in code that is harder to read, debug, and use. Many devs consider doing this an anti-pattern.

Comment: On an unrelated note. If you have not yet implemented EF6 in this specific project I urge you to consider using EF Core (v3) as it will make any future efforts to reuse the code in .net core projects easier as well as porting your project to .net core if the need ever arises. EF Core is also in active development and EF6 is no longer getting any new features (only triage fixes).

Comment: @Igor Hmm i followed a paid tutorial by Mosh Hamedani. The reason why EF6 was chosen was primarily the underlying system is not compatible with a modern version of EF at this stage

Comment: EF Core v3 is compatible with .net framework 4.7.2 (and higher) / .net standard 2.0 / and .net core. You should be OK unless you are using a very dated version of .net framework maybe?

Comment: Ok i could uninstall it via PMC and try it out but i will probably have to check the documentation to ensure the underlying system is compatible with that.... for now i suppose the original issue remains.

Comment: `paid tutorial by Mosh Hamedani` ← The name does not mean much to me, sorry. Do check out this answer on Software Engineering: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/220126/244226

Comment: https://codewithmosh.com/courses I will have a read on that link and the "Service Pattern" but at present i would imagine im deep into the project :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Entity Framework 6, the [`Include`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbquery-1.include?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#system-data-entity-infrastructure-dbquery-1-include(system-string)) method is defined on the `DbQuery<T>` class (`DbSet<T>` is derived from `DbQuery<T>`). Your `GetAll` method on the other hand returns an `IEnumerable<T>`. The compiler does not know that you return a `DbSet<T>` in the form of the `IEnumerable<T>`, hence the method is not offered.

If you want to offer the caller of `GetAll` to use the `Include` method, you can change the return type, e.g.:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    DbQuery<T> GetAll();
}
```

Please note by using `DbQuery<T>` as your return type, the interface shows that you are using Entity Framework and you do not hide this detail from the user of the interface. In order to hide this, you can offer another method that accepts a parameter for the include and still returns an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    IEnumerable<T> GetAllWithInclude(string include);
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly DbContext _context = null;
    private readonly DbSet<T> _entities;

    public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _entities = _context.Set<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _entities;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAllWithInclude(string include)
    {
        return _entities.Include(include);
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed if i changed IEnumerable to IQueryable Include then showed up too but will take your advice above